Can I prevent mirroring with a specific display?
I have a 2019 MacBook Pro (Intel Silicon) running Ventura (13.6.7). It is often connected to a Dell P2310H monitor, which I always want to use as an extended display. Mirroring frequently starts without my initiating it. Is there a way to prevent screen mirroring with a specific monitor?
